# Unable to get Azure monitoring metrics from the REST API

Tags: azure, monitoring

I retrieve metric definitions using this:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-grp-id}/providers/microsoft.classiccompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions?api-version=2015-07-01
```

which returns

```
{
"id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-group-id}/providers/microsoft.classiccompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions",
"value": [
    {
        "resourceUri": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-group-id}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}",
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-group-id}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}",
        "name": {
            "value": "\\Memory\\AvailableMemory",
            "localizedValue": "Memory available"
        },
        "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "unit": "Bytes",
        "primaryAggregationType": "Average",
        "ResourceUri": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-group-id}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}",
        "ResourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-group-id}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}",
        "metricAvailabilities": [a11bbc020fdd/resourceGroups/cldy-az-res-grp-test-1/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/cldy-az-vm-test-1","metricAvailabilities":[{"timeGrain":"PT1H","retention":"P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S","location":{"tableEndpoint":"https://cldyazresgrptest19563.table.core.windows.net/","tableInfo":[{"tableName":"WADMetricsPT1HP10DV2S20170331",
```

....

But when I attempt to fetch metric "\\Memory\\AvailableMemory" with

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{res-grp-id}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2016-09-01&$filter=%28name.value+eq+%27%5CMemory%5CAvailableMemory%27%29+and+aggregationType+eq+%27Average%27+and+startTime+eq+2017-04-06T10%3A01%3A00Z+and+endTime+eq+2017-04-07T10%3A01%3A00Z+and+timeGrain+eq+duration%27PT1H%27
```

I get an error message:

```
{"code":"NotFound","message":"Please make sure your provider: Microsoft.ClassicCompute is properly registered with insights and retry"}
```

The filter param in the URL is

```
(name.value eq '\Memory\AvailableMemory') and aggregationType eq 'Average' and startTime eq 2017-04-06T10:01:00Z and endTime eq 2017-04-07T10:01:00Z and timeGrain eq duration'PT1H'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a supported resource type through metrics API.  The supported types and metrics are here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics

The Memory metric is a guest agent metric and will be written to WADMetrics table in customer storage account. The metric definition API returns back a SAS key to these tables but there is no metrics REST API to access this data today. Customer will need to access this data through storage APIs.

Comment: I get the same error when attempting to use `Percentage CPU` metric, which is listed as supported. 

     `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/{vm-id}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2016-09-01&$filter=%28name.value+eq+%27Percentage+CPU%27%29+and+aggregationType+eq+%27Average%27+and+startTime+eq+2017-04-08T10%3A01%3A00Z+and+endTime+eq+2017-04-09T10%3A01%3A00Z+and+timeGrain+eq+duration%27PT1H%27`

Comment: The resource type Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualmachines is currently not supported in the metrics API.  Please refer to the supported resource types.  Can you try with a virtual machine that is of resource type Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics