# Consume Azure Monitor Rest API from .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, monitor

I am pretty new to Azure. Following is the task I am trying to achieve:

I wanted to consume Azure Monitor Rest API from .Net application using C# code and wanted to display few metrics(any couple of metrics) on the web page(I am using ASP.Net).

For this, I created Azure AD, got the subscription ID, Tenant ID, Client Secret and Client ID from Azure portal. All that I have to do is from .Net end, which is balance and I couldn't find proper resources to achieve this task.

Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: What kind of ,NET app are you using to make your API call?  A console app or some kind of web app?  Or Javascript?

Comment: i am trying a web app. But anything should be fine form. all I need is to get few metrics of azure monitor and display it

Comment: Here are some examples using C# and Powershell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-collector-api

Comment: @KevinRaffay, Thanks for your response once again. But the article you shared says "HTTP Data Collector API to send data to Log Analytics from a REST API client". But I wanted to access the Azure Metrics API that collects the Metrics data( GET https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01) and display the metrics(atleast couple of the metrics) in the web page or in console application using C#.net.

Comment: Have you read all the documentation?  Google seems to return a lot of info related to that REST API.  There are also examples on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288846/unable-to-get-azure-monitoring-metrics-from-the-rest-api).  The API doesn't matter, if you need help understanding how to make REST calls in ASP.NET, please post a new question.

Comment: All that I need is how can I consume an Azure Metrics Rest API from .net application. Be it be console or web based application. As I was pretty new, I was looking for some resource where it guides me step-by-step approach, which I wasn't able to find. Could you please let me know if there is any website that could explain clearly to achieve this task?

Answer (score 7):

1. If you need to extract metric definitions (structure of azure monitor metrics) then you need to use `MetricDefinitions` web point. Detailed documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list).
2. If you need to get monitoring metric values you need to use `Metrics` endpoint. Documentation link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list).

For both cases you need to use **MonitorClient** object from [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor) nuget package.

You can review good examples how to extract metrics [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/)(extract one-dimension metrics) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/monitor-dotnet-multidimensional-metrics-api/)(extract multi-dimension metrics).

Also follow up to couple helpful links:

- [Monitoring Concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring/monitoring-data-collection)
- [Supported Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics)